# why use exit() instead of return in c?

Tags: c, return, exit

I don't know what the use of exit() is

Consider the two following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *ptr;

  if ((ptr = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
    printf("Error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *ptr;

  if ((ptr = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What are the differences between the two of them ?

Comment: If you're not in `main`, but in a different function, `return` will exit from that function and not from the whole program.

Comment: In C (but not necessarily in C++) returning from the *initial* call to a standard `main()` has exactly the effect of calling `exit()` with the erstwhile return value as the argument.  `exit()`, however, will terminate the program from anywhere within -- any function of any thread -- including from a reentrant call to `main()`.